# Volley GET JsonObjectRequest not executed in order, response arrived later

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I implement a function to get data from server using volley :

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://************";


    mRequestStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {//[1]

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {//[2]

                    long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;

                    Log.i("AppInfo", "Response: " + response.toString());


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest); //[3]

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));//[4]
```

The problem is that the response does not arrive quickly, so as explained in the comments in the code, the sequence of executing was supposed to be 1,2,3,4

but instead, it executed as 1,3,4,2

Comment: The sequence of executing is fully correct and can only be 1->3->4->2, as 1), 3) & 4) is synchronous code that is executed instantly one by one, but 2) is asynchronous callback that takes time to be executed. This callback is here to not block the main thread of your application

Comment: @Teempy Understood, so what if I want to be executed in sequence ( synchronous )? Is there a way to achieve this?  Since the rest of the code after this part depends on the response of the request.

Comment: Or what is the best approach to do the intended work

Comment: If you have some code that must be executed right after you get the response, then you place it in the actual response i.e. ```onResponse``` callback. You can also call your class methods from this callback.